# Sylius - How to assign a Channel to a Product programmatically?

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am trying to assign a Channel to my products created programmatically, so they will be displayed on shop. Unfortunately, there is no documentation for this use case.

Here is how I create my products:

```
$productFactory = $this->container->get('sylius.factory.product');
$productManager = $this->container->get('sylius.manager.product');
$productRepository = $this->get('sylius.repository.product');
$productVariantFactory = $this->get('sylius.factory.product_variant');
$productVariantRepository = $this->get('sylius.repository.product_variant');
$channelPricingFactory = $this->get('sylius.factory.channel_pricing');
$channelPricingRepository = $this->get('sylius.repository.channel_pricing');

//CREATE PRODUCT

$product = $factory->createNew();
$product->setName('TEST 2 - '.$title);
$product->setCode($this->generateRandomString());
$product->setSlug($this->generateRandomString());
$productRepository->add($product);

//CREATE VARIANT & ATTACH IT TO PRODUCT

$variant = $productVariantFactory->createNew();
$variant->setName('TEST 2 - '.$title);
$variant->setCode($this->generateRandomString());
$variant->setProduct($product);
$productVariantRepository->add($variant);

//CREATE PRICE & ATTACH IT TO VARIANT

$channelPricing = $channelPricingFactory->createNew();
$channelPricing->setPrice(999);
$channelPricing->setOriginalPrice(999);
$channelPricing->setChannelCode('US_WEB');
$channelPricing->setProductVariant($variant);
$channelPricingRepository->add($channelPricing);
```

Unfortunately, the products are not linked to a Channel:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question:

You have one product variant, but Product variant implements ProductVariantInterface which extends TranslatableInterface. So we need one translation to make it appear and work. To add the translation:

```
$productVariant->setCurrentLocale('fr_FR');
$productVariantTranslation = $productVariant->getTranslation();
```

or

```
$productVariantTranslation = $productVariant->getTranslation($locale);
```

after you can add a name or not:

```
$productVariantTranslation->setName('What a product variant!');
```

after:

```
$product->addVariant($productVariant);
$this->entityManager->persist($product);
```

You will have your product variant on line.

Another thing is that:

```
$channelPricingRepository = $this->get('sylius.repository.channel_pricing');
$channelPricingRepository->add($entity);
```

it's going to flush directly data to DB in each call. In the example you are going to flush 3 times instead only one. In bigger proccess with many "add" this can be a lack of performance. You can simply;

```
$this->entityManager->persist($entity); //Many times
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed to create my products (to attach them then to my entities):

```
function createProduct($livre,$options){

    $title = $livre['title'];
    $prix = $livre['prix'];

    // SYLIUS REPOSITORIES LOAD

    $productFactory = $options['sylius_factory_product'];
    $productRepository = $options['sylius_repository_product'];
    $productVariantFactory = $options['sylius_factory_product_variant'];
    $productVariantRepository = $options['sylius_repository_product_variant'];
    $channelPricingFactory = $options['sylius_factory_channel_pricing'];
    $channelPricingRepository = $options['sylius_repository_channel_pricing'];

    //CREATE PRODUCT

    $product = $productFactory->createNew();
    $product->setName($title);
    $product->setCode($title.'_'.$this->generateRandomString());
    $product->setSlug($title.'_'.$this->generateRandomString());
    $productRepository->add($product);


    //CREATE VARIANT & ATTACH IT TO PRODUCT

    $variant = $productVariantFactory->createNew();
    $variant->setName($title. 'Variant');
    $variant->setCode($title.'_'.$this->generateRandomString());
    $variant->setProduct($product);
    $productVariantRepository->add($variant);


    //CREATE PRICE & ATTACH IT TO VARIANT

    $channelPricing = $channelPricingFactory->createNew();
    $channelPricing->setPrice($prix*100);
    $channelPricing->setOriginalPrice($prix*100);
    $channelPricing->setChannelCode('CH');
    $channelPricing->setProductVariant($variant);
    $channelPricingRepository->add($channelPricing);

    $productId = $product->getId();

    return $productId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the channel to the product like this:

```
$channelCode = 'US_WEB'
$channelRepository = $this->get('sylius.repository.channel');
$channel = $channelRepository->findOneBy(array('code' => $channelCode));
$product->addChannel($channel);
```